# Set 24 hours TimeInterval in Where Clause of SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

I need to query a table in an sql server, in which the Query results to be filtered between yesterday's 5:00Pm to  Today's 5:00PM. But the Table contains Date and Time in seperate fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE (DateCol=cast (GETDATE() as DATE) AND TimeCol<'17:00:00') 
OR (DateCol=cast (GETDATE()-1 as DATE) AND TimeCol>'17:00:00')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that or be an and?

Comment: No, because that would be impossible as something cannot belong to yesterday and today at the same time.